# Get Near by places data with longitude lattitude using google map api 3 without loading the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i want to use google map api. and want to get near by places data by specifying longitude latitude.

my question is that...

is it possible to get near by places data with longitude-latitude without loading the google map ?

i have checked " Retrieve predictions from the autocomplete service " but its not returning longitude-latitude related information.

Comment: Keep in mind the [Terms of Service, section 10.1.1.g](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) restrict usage of Google data without displaying a map.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms  - Here is written that we can use google map api data without using google map.

Comment: That only applies to Autocomplete. As far as I understand you are looking for [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map div and hide that div in your application. In the background, you can call google map and get near by places and do what ever you want.

```
<div class="row" id="map-canvas" width="100%" height="400" style="display:none;"></div>

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    map.places.search(search, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

              console.log(results[i]);
          }


      } else {
          alert('unable to get the data from google map');
      }
    });
```

Adjust the functionality as per your requirement. to run this application you might need to make little modification. refer to google map place search api for batter understanding.